# Autodesk forge viewer document failed to load

Tags: angular, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm trying to display 3d files on my ionic/angular app using autodesk forge. So far, I followed until step 3 of this tutorial : https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/ I felt like I just wanted a basic viewer so the rest was unnecessary. I managed to prep the file for viewer according to this tutorial : https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer I was able to successfully translate a dwg file to svf and get the urn of that file. Then I placed both urn and my access token in my app but I got an error while trying to view the file -

- GET http://localhost:8100/{URN}?domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100 404 (Not Found)
- Failed fetching Forge manifest

This is how I'm using the viewer.

In my html file :

```
    <div id="container" #container></div>
```

In .ts file :

```
@ViewChild('container') container;
...

private viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D;
/*
  tried the below viewerOptions as well as just {env: 'local'}
*/
  private viewerOptions = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    api: 'derivativeV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
    getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
        var token = '{TOKEN}';
        var timeInSeconds = 3600; // Use value provided by Forge Authentication (OAuth) API
        onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
    }
  };
  private urn : string = "{base64_encoded_urn}";
...
ngAfterViewInit(){
    if(this.is3d) {
      let config3d = {
        memory: {
            limit:  2000 // in MB
        }
      };
//loadscripts loads the scripts style.min.css and viewer3D.min.js
      this.cadViewer.loadscripts().then(() => Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(this.viewerOptions, () => (this.viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(this.container.nativeElement, config3d)).start())) //start(this.svfURL)
      Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(this.urn, this.onDocumentLoadSuccess, this.onDocumentLoadFailure);
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.viewer.finish();
    this.viewer = null;
    Autodesk.Viewing.shutdown();
  }

  onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
    // viewerDocument is an instance of Autodesk.Viewing.Document
    let defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
    this.viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
  }

  onDocumentLoadFailure() {
    console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
  }
```

Not sure why I'm getting the error, or why its trying to make a get request to this http://localhost:8100/URN?domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100

EDIT :

response from the designdata GET request (to check progress) :

```
{"result":"success","urn":"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YnVja2V0MTJzL3Zpc3VhbGl6YXRpb25fLV9hZXJpYWwuZHdn",
"acceptedJobs":{
    "output":{
        "destination":{"region":"us"},
        "formats":[{
            "type":"svf",
            "views":["2d","3d"]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

response from the POST job :

```
{"urn":"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YnVja2V0MTJzL3Zpc3VhbGl6YXRpb25fLV9hZXJpYWwuZHdn",
"derivatives":[
    {"hasThumbnail":"true",
    "children":[
        {"urn":"urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YnVja2V0MTJzL3Zpc3VhbGl6YXRpb25fLV9hZXJpYWwuZHdn/output/properties.db",
        "role":"Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase","mime":"application/autodesk-db",
        "guid":"cb73c076-d3cd-a725-754f-a64cd8c07648","type":"resource","status":"success"
        },
        {"guid":"6882be48-6626-5238-d3df-94e9f0a0019d","type":"geometry","role":"2d","name":"2D View",
        "viewableID":"Model","status":"success","hasThumbnail":"true","progress":"complete",
        "children":[
            {"urn":"urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YnVja2V0MTJzL3Zpc3VhbGl6YXRpb25fLV9hZXJpYWwuZHdn/output/visualization_-_aerial-Model_100.png","role":"thumbnail","mime":"image/png","guid":"29eb53a9-fc30-98f4-5f6d-440aecb0c133","type":"resource","resolution":[100,100],"status":"success"
            },
            {"urn":"urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YnVja2V0MTJzL3Zpc3VhbGl6YXRpb25fLV9hZXJpYWwuZHdn/output/visualization_-_aerial-Model_200.png","role":"thumbnail","mime":"image/png","guid":"239661cc-f655-5161-a426-d683b2b06351","type":"resource","resolution":[200,200],"status":"success"
            },
            {"urn":"urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YnVja2V0MTJzL3Zpc3VhbGl6YXRpb25fLV9hZXJpYWwuZHdn/output/visualization_-_aerial-Model_400.png","role":"thumbnail","mime":"image/png","guid":"c7d505a0-3a54-ea0c-8a4a-8315cc5622d1","type":"resource","resolution":[400,400],"status":"success"
            },
            {"urn":"urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YnVja2V0MTJzL3Zpc3VhbGl6YXRpb25fLV9hZXJpYWwuZHdn/output/7c4897c9-0839-9915-b3e2-5d824c1392f0_f2d/primaryGraphics.f2d","role":"graphics","mime":"application/autodesk-f2d","guid":"2d28aef5-8be3-b52e-0301-1476ea6607e7","type":"resource","status":"success"
            }]
        },
        {"guid":"149d819a-f59a-9de3-b42d-15f1269b41df","type":"geometry","role":"3d","name":"3D Views","status":"success","viewableID":"Model-3D","progress":"complete","hasThumbnail":"true",
        "children":[
            {"urn":"urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YnVja2V0MTJzL3Zpc3VhbGl6YXRpb25fLV9hZXJpYWwuZHdn/output/dwg.svf","role":"graphics","mime":"application/autodesk-svf","guid":"e30bd031-d13a-a976-9153-78100829986a","type":"resource","status":"success"
            },
            {"guid":"bd71b4a2-8c04-f1bd-44ed-3fb8d20a40e9","type":"view","role":"3d","name":"*Initial*","camera":[133.54763793945312,35.416358947753906,12.068309783935547,2.1020402908325195,26.13581657409668,1.6313152313232422,0,0,1,2.1939313411712646,0.9602929949760437,66.62181854248047,0]
            },
            {"guid":"3c9d59fb-3147-a570-4103-1a766ac78d9b","type":"view","role":"3d","name":"RenderView","camera":[94.6693344116211,32.67140579223633,8.981308937072754,2.1020402908325195,26.13581657409668,1.6313152313232422,0,0,1,1.3722333908081055,0.9602929949760437,66.62181854248047,0]
            },
            {"urn":"urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YnVja2V0MTJzL3Zpc3VhbGl6YXRpb25fLV9hZXJpYWwuZHdn/output/dwg.svf.png01_thumb_400x400.png","role":"thumbnail","mime":"image/png","guid":"89cecf0c-543e-4d26-b5bf-d9c00f0a761b","type":"resource","resolution":[400,400]
            },
            {"urn":"urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YnVja2V0MTJzL3Zpc3VhbGl6YXRpb25fLV9hZXJpYWwuZHdn/output/dwg.svf.png01_thumb_200x200.png","role":"thumbnail","mime":"image/png","guid":"a369bc4b-41c4-4d30-b913-0e636e474ece","type":"resource","resolution":[200,200]
            },
            {"urn":"urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YnVja2V0MTJzL3Zpc3VhbGl6YXRpb25fLV9hZXJpYWwuZHdn/output/dwg.svf.png01_thumb_100x100.png","role":"thumbnail","mime":"image/png","guid":"707c2d20-38df-4527-a7bd-04267763d5b6","type":"resource","resolution":[100,100]
            }
            ]
        }
        ],
        "name":"visualization_-_aerial.dwg","progress":"complete","outputType":"svf","status":"success"
    }
    ],
"hasThumbnail":"true","progress":"complete","type":"manifest","region":"US","version":"1.0","status":"success"}
```

Comment: Does prefixing your urn with:  `urn:` produce any results ?

Comment: @SamuelMiddendorp it doesn't give "failed to fetch manifest" anymore, ie it doesn't go to onDocumentLoadFailure method, but it gives this in the console "DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js.map" and in the network tab, I get errors for lmvworker.min.js, allstrings.json, the localhost url in question and this one "https://api-js.mixpanel.com/decide/?verbose=1&version=1&lib=web&token=7cecb637d6468a8b61f388bbb82072ee&ip=1&_=1594648425237"

Comment: Actually, now i'm getting the failed fetching forge manifest again...

Comment: Your Urn has the following format ? `urn:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bXktYnVja2V0L215LWF3ZXNvbWUtZm9yZ2UtZmlsZS5ydnQ`

Comment: yes @SamuelMiddendorp

Comment: please try again and confirm if the models are showing as expected.

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves still getting the same error

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves any idea how I can solve this?